# Continuity/measurability of a complicated extension of a family of continuous functions

Tags: gn.general-topology, measure-theory

Bonjour/bonsoir à tous et à toutes.

I've two questions related to something on which I'm working. I've already tried to discuss about them elsewhere, but it hasn't been fruitful so far.

**Edit (4 Dic 2011).** Let me simplify the original text according to the comments of fedja and Michael Greinecker.

Let $\mathcal{X} \equiv (X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ and $\mathcal{Y} \equiv (Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)$ be topological spaces, $I \ne \emptyset$ an index set, $\{X_i\}_{i \in I}$ a chain of $(2^X, \subseteq)$ such that $\textstyle \bigcup_{ i \in I} X_i = X$ and $X_i$ is dense in $\mathcal{X}$ for all $i \in I$, $\{f_i\}_{i \in I}$ a family of continuous functions $(X_i, X_i \cap \mathcal{O}_X) \to \mathcal{Y}$ such that $f_j$ extends $f_i$, for $i,j \in I$, if $X_i \subseteq X_j$. Then, set $f := \textstyle\bigcup_{i \in I} f_i$ (identifying each $f_i$ with its graph). Now come the questions.

> **Question 1.** Is $f$ a continuous function $(X, X \cap \mathcal{O}_X)
> > \to \mathcal{Y}$?

I've some clues that the answer to Question 1 *may be* negative, but so far I wasn't able to find out any counterexample by myself. In any case, if the answer is really "No", it will make still sense to ask for the following:

> **Question 2.** Is $f$ a Borel function $(X, \mathfrak{B}(X \cap
> > \mathcal{O}_X)) \to (Y,
> > \mathfrak{B}(\mathcal{O}_Y))$? Here,
>   provided $(W,\mathcal{O}_W)$ is a
>   topological space, I'm denoting by
>   $\mathfrak{B}(\mathcal{O}_W)$ the
>   Borel algebra on $W$ generated by the
>   open sets of $\mathcal{O}_W$.

**Partial results (updated to 6 Dec 2011).** fedja proved below in the comments that the answer to Question 1 is affirmative if the topology of $Y$ is such that points can be separated from closed sets. On another hand, Yulia Kuznetsova showed that Q1 is false assuming that $\mathcal{X}$ is the interval $[0,1]$ (with its usual subspace topology) and $\mathcal{Y}$ is the Sierpiński space ([here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/82623/continuity-measurability-of-a-complicated-extension-of-a-family-of-continuous-fun/82712#82712)).

Thank you in advance for any hint.

Comment: An obvious remark is that if you can separate a point from a closed set in $Y$, then $f$ is continuous. Take $x$, take a neighborhood $U$ of $y=f(x)=f_i(x)$; choose a neighborhood $W$ of $y$ such that its closure is contained in $U$. Choose a neighborhood $V$ of $x$ such that $f(D_i\cap V)\subset W$. Then for every $j$ and $x'\in V\cap D_j$, the image $f(x')$ is contained in the closure of $W$ by density of $D_i$ in $V$ and continuity of $f_j$. So, you need bad topological spaces for a counterexample. Also, the one-to-one condition is useless: you can always change $f$ to $(id,f)$.   

Comment: I think your notation is needlessly complicated. One can simplify the problem a lot if one identifies a function with its graph. Then, $(f_i)$ is a chain of sets itself, $f=\bigcup_i f_i$ and one can assum w.l.o.g. that $X=D=\bigcup_i\text{dom}f_i$. 


Comment: @fedja. Obvious?! I'd say it's a great remark. @Michael. You're clearly right. I'm going to edit the OP according to the comments of you both and withdraw what is actually unnecessary.

Comment: Look at Engelking 2.1.13 and at the exercise 2.1.J. It claims that a sufficient condition is that $X_i$ are locally finite, and that there is a counterexample if they are not.

Comment: Sorry, that was for closed $X_i$, and since yours are dense, this will not work.

Comment: @Yulia. Thanks for the reference. Clearly, up to the trivial case in which I is finite (possibly after removing all duplicates), `$\{X_i\}_{i \in I}$` won't generally satisfy the condition of being a locally finite cover. All the more that Engelking's Prop. 2.1.13 (pp. 72-73) applies to locally finite _closed_ covers, as you noticed in your last comment. Nevertheless, `$\{X_i\}_{i \in I}$` isn't a completely arbitrary cover of $\mathcal{X}$, here: it's a chain in $(2^X,\subseteq)$ and each of its members are dense in $\mathcal{X}$. So I don't see how this could imply a negative answer to Q1.

Comment: On another hand, Gillman and Jerison's 1960 result addressed by problem 2.1.J on page 74 states a kind of extensibility characterization applying, in a cumulative sense, to _every_ continuous function from a topological subspace of $\mathcal{X}$ to the interval [0,1] (endowed with the obvious topology). P.S.: to be sure we're talking about the same things, let me mark that I'm referring herein to the 1989 Heldermann-Verlag edition of Engelking's _General Topology_.

Answer (score 2):

Look if this works as a counterexample to Q1: Let $Y=\{0,1\}$ be a two-point set such that 1 is open and 0 is not, and let $X=[0,1]$ in the usual topology. Let $X_i = [0,1] \setminus \{2^{-k}: k>i\}$. Put $f_i(0)=1$, $f_i(2^{-k})=0$ for all $k$, and $f_i(x)=1$ for other $x$. Then every $f_i$ is continuous but $f$ is not. Right?

Comment: (continue because of problems with TeX) .. and let $X_i=\{0\}\cup [2^{-k},1]$. Put $f_i(0)=1$, $f_i(2^{-k})=0$ for all $k$, and $f_i(x)=1$ for other $x$. Then every $f_i$ is continuous but $f$ is not. Right?

Comment: Sorry, need to correct this: obviously $X_i$ are not dense like this, one should put $X_i = [0,1] \setminus \{2^k: k>i\}$.

Comment: Yes, I know how to type TeX... Done. This time it worked, but before the same text didn't want to show after multiple edits.

Comment: If $\{1\}$ is open, then $\{0\}$ is closed, hence it can’t be dense. But you don’t really need the latter in the argument, it works with $Y$ being the Sierpiński space.

Comment: Also, the $U_k$ are not used anywhere, and there is a missing $-$ in the definition of $X_i$.

Comment: Emil - corrected, thank you. I didn't want 0 to be dense, I wanted to explain briefly that the only open sets are $\emptyset,\{1\}$ and $Y$.

Comment: @Yulia. Too bad that your nice counterexample doesn't work also for the 2nd question. In any case, I'm going to edit the OP and add that you replied Q1 in the negative.

Comment: @Salvo - if you do not require $X_i$ to be a chain (i.e. linearly ordered), it can be easily modified to yield a non-measurable function. Are they really a chain in your applications?

Comment: @Yulia. Yes, I need it to be linearly ordered.

Comment: Maybe one can modify it to be non-measurable. The task is to find such a *chain* $F_i$ that:
every $F_i$ is closed;
$E=\cup F_i$ is nowhere dense and not Borel.
Then the counterexample will be given by $f_i|_{F_i}=0$, $f_i|_{X\setminus E}=1$ where $\\{0,1\\}$ is the Sierpinski space with 1 open.


Answer (score 1):

Sorry if this doesn't work - but:
I think one can modify the example to yieald a non-measurable function. The task is to find such a *chain* $F_i$ that:
every $F_i$ is closed;
$E=\cup F_i$ is not Borel;
$X\setminus E$ is dense in $X$.
Then the counterexample will be given by $f_i|_{F_i}=0$, $f_i|_{X\setminus E}=1$ where $\{0,1\}$ is the Sierpinski space with 1 open.

This is most easily constructed in a non-metrizable dyadic space: $X=\{0,1\}^A$ (where $\{0,1\}$ is a Hausdorff two-point set), $A$ is uncountable. Split $A=\cup_{i\in S} A_i$ into a noncountable disjoint union of subsets $A_i$, every $A_i$ being infinite and countable. For $B\subset A$, let $p_B:X\to \{0,1\}^B$ be the natural projection. On $S$, choose a linear order without a maximal element. For every $i\in S$, put $F_i = \{ x\in X: p_{A_k}(x)=0 \forall k\ge i\}$.

If $E=\cup F_i$, then clearly $X\setminus E$ is dense. I realize also that $E$ is not Baire, but I cannot say whether it is Borel.